# Can I include data with GET request that should be cached (in a Chrome App)

Tags: google-chrome, caching, http-headers, google-chrome-app

I am developing a Chrome App that needs to work off-line, i.e., I want it to use the App Cache, rather than sending a request to the server, as much as possible.  However, should it be necessary to hit the server, then I would like to include a few bytes of data (so the server can collect and analyse some statistics about, for example, how many previous requests were served by the cache alone).

I can not send the data bytes in the URL query, because this defeats the cache (and is a well known technique for ensuring the cache is bypassed - exactly what I do NOT want to do).

I can't use a POST request, as that will also defeat the cache.

I have thought about including data in a header, but am unsure how, and unsure if this will do the trick as everything I have found about this idea recommends against it.  I do not want to get in the trap of relying on something completely undocumented in case it stops working in the future (and I am not sure what will work today).

Can I include data in a GET request that will have absolutely no effect on the App Cache (in Chrome in particular), but is available to the server if and when the request makes it that far?

Comment: Chrome Apps don't use the HTML5 Application Cache. All their content is included in the CRX, so they're offline by default. See http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html for an overview.

Comment: I guess I should have focused on "App Cache" instead of mentioning "Chrome App". My Chrome App does indeed use the Application Cache as it contains <webview>s.

Answer (score 0):

See comment above; this question isn't really about Chrome Apps. It's more about webapps that use App Cache.

It might be helpful to decouple normal web requests from the reporting feature. You are trying to piggyback the stats on the normal requests, but there doesn't seem to be a need to do so. Moreover, for the occasional client that caches perfectly, you'll never hear from that client because the reporting never occurs. So even in the best case the design would have been flaky.

Instead, you could increment a counter every time you make a request that might be cacheable, and keep it somewhere persistent like in localStorage. Then periodically report it to a noncached destination. You can then subtract the traffic you are receiving at the web server (which represents uncached requests) from that reported total (which represents all requests, cached or not). The difference is cached requests.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the data at the server at the time the request hits it. My question is about transferring data with a GET, not so much about how it is to be used.